# html - is is possible to group images?

Tags: html

If I have a group of pictures, how can I get the browser to wrap them as a single image?  For example images a.jpg,b.jpg,c.jpg stay in a group d.jpg,e.jpg,f.jpg,g.jpg stay in a group, etc.  So that if a.jpg is on one line then c.jpg is also on that line and not wrapped to the next line?

Answer (score 1):

Try the `white-space` CSS property:

```css
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='nowrap'>
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/200/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/200/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/200/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/200/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/200/200' />
</div>
<div class='nowrap'>
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/250/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/250/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/250/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/250/200' />
  <img src='http://lorempizza.com/250/200' />
</div>
```